# how to run subquery on results of initial query

Tags: graphql, subquery

I am new to graphql and have a simple query returning results. i then want to loop the retuned results and run another query. I am after the data returned from the second query.

1st query

```
{
  queryOne (where: {deployer: "id"}) {
    id
    ...
  state {
      constants
    }
  }
```

`constants` will contain an array of 2 rows. which i can ref as `result.data.state.constants[0]` and `result.data.state.constants[1]`. On these 2 I would like to run the following

```
queryTwo (where: {id: result.data.state.constants[0]})  {
    id
    ...
  }
```

Comment: It's 2022 and i'm still searching for this answer, how were you able to resolve it?

Comment: I looped through 1st results after saving results of query1

Comment: okay thanks. I was just considering the efficiency of that. I did same.

Comment: i believe the contract/subgraph (not too familiar with terminology) needs to support it. if it doesn't support it then you won't be able to